# Probability Question : I have three locks and three keys (only One correct key for each lock).

Tags: probability

What is the probability that all locks are unlocked by choosing one key and one lock randomly at a time?
Note: After correctly choosing a key to unlock a lock, the key is kept back with the other two keys while the lock is kept aside. So after unlocking first lock, I am left with just 2 locks to choose from but I have all the three keys to choose from.

Comment: Can you at least answer this question: What is the probability that the first lock is unlocked?

Comment: I am so sorry but I dont know as I am confused over this. I think It should be 1/3.

Comment: That’s right. Now when you get to the second lock, has anything really changed? You still have one chance in three of picking the right key, so the probability of unlocking the second lock is ... ?

Comment: But in the first chance, I had three locks to choose from to apply my chosen key. In that scenario as well Would you say my answer was correct? Secondly, after successfully unlocking the first lock I ll hv to choose a lock from remaining 2 locks while I still choose a key from all the three keys.......

Comment: The choice of locks doesn’t make any difference. No matter which one you pick, you still have one chance in three of picking the right key.

Comment: So the correct answer should be 1/3+1/3+1/3 or (1/3)*(1/3)*(1/3)  ?

Comment: Stop a moment and think: $\frac13+\frac13+\frac13=1$. If that were right, you’d be certain to unlock all three locks! But yes, $\frac13\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac13$ is correct. When you want the probability that $A$ **and** $B$ occur, where $A$ and $B$ are independent events, you multiply their individual probabilities.

Comment: Shouldn't we condition on the event that we guess the right key for the first lock ? If that event occurs, then we can rule out that key for the other two locks. I suppose it depends on the precise conditions. For each lock, exactly one key unlocks it, but are there keys that unlock more than once lock ?

Comment: You write, "so after unlocking first lock, I am left with just 2 locks to choose from but I have all the three keys to choose from." If this is the case, you're always randomly choosing one key out of the three keys available, and your probability of choosing the right key on each trial remains as $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score -1):

Possible combinations are 3×2×1=3!=6
In which 1 is correct
P(A)=1÷6=0.166